# If a CPU is 80% busy consistently, does it mean that it is 80% less responsive?

Tags: cpu, cpu-usage, conceptual

If I run an application in a CPU which is busy 80% (i.e. CPU usage, not load avg) of the time, will the application become 80% less responsive?

Comment: Unlikely. How do you measure "reponsive"?

Comment: Define "responsive". Do you mean how fast you can lets say launch a new browser window? Or how fast you can execute some heavy tasks?

Comment: CPU busy time is not the only factor (and "responsiveness" is a rather fuzzy concept) - e.g. I've seen apps that ran consistently at 90% CPU idle, but IO waiting (disk access) was way through the roof.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but doesn't a question like this belong on a site like superuser.com, and not stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot equate like this,

- Identify the process which takes 80% CPU
- Identify the Application generating this load
- You have to investigate to see, conclude the issues (System / Application Related / Configuration related)

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the 80% from? There's a difference between CPU usage and CPU load (you can use the unix top command to get both). The percentage just shows what percentage of all running threads is spent on CPU, load shows how many threads are waiting in the queue to be executed ... in either case those numbers won't give you much information about CPU responsiveness, you need to do some more investigation.